# Can't resolve com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-plus

I can't seem to resolve the Plus class from the Google Play services library. I've already imported the Google Play library into the project as an Android Library project through Eclipse. I'm also following the basic [example](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_4_initialize_the_googleapiclient) from the getting started page.

My onCreate is currently this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API, null)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
    .build();
}
```

Eclipse flags the Plus class names because it can't resolve them so the code doesn't build.

Comment: I'm wondering if this needs you to check for updates in the SDK and maybe rebuild the Play Services library project. I notice that link was updated only yesterday. I'm not in a position to check for updates myself at the moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you [NickT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440010/nickt). I just updated Google Play Services and the Plus class came with the library.

Comment: Make sure that you have the Google Play Services Version 15 or higher in your SDK manager.

Answer (score 1):

This might sort out the issue

`mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
        .build();`

Comment: It did. At the time, the constant Plus.API and Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN wasn't available. I ran an update later that evening and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the meta-data in the manifest?

The all steps indicated in the [getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) should be everything you need.

Comment: This right? --> <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
I had an xml error with it at one point but that's because I didn't import the library. The getting started guide should have everything I need.

Comment: Yes that is correct. You've cleaned and rebuilt? You have the correct imports? Seems like you're on the right path.

Comment: I even imported "import com.google.android.gms.plus.*;". The class I'm  looking for is "import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus", but I can't seem to retrieve it.

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your app/build.gradle:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'