# unable to find plus class from google services library

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I'm following the tutorial from google+ API integeration from this google docs example https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in Everything worked well but I'm just not able to find Plus class from the google services library. This guy [Can't resolve com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790651/cant-resolve-com-google-android-gms-plus-plus-class) had the same issue but he resolved it by updating google services library from sdk but it my case its already updated but I'm not able to resolve it. here is the code for adding Plus API in to google client

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(Scopes.PLUS_ME)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the scope in mGoogleApiClient. Add it to GoogleSignInOptions object. Try this -

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    googleSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.google_sign_in);
    googleSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
    googleSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
```